# How to get SharePoint online Groups using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to get sharepoint groups using graph api instead of REST API Call

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Microsoft Graph doesn't expose an endpoint that allows you to get the information of SharePoint Group.

If you has this requirement, you could vote [this idea on Microsoft Graph UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/35989975-get-sharepoint-security-groups-members-using-micro).